# Logic problem, proposed by Euler

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A professor of mine asked me this challenge.
"(Proposed by Euler) A person bought horses and oxen. Paid 31 shields per horse and 20 per ox, and found that all oxen cost 7 shields more than all the horses. How many horses and oxen were bought? "
And I is not getting ...
Called C the amount of horses and cattle amount of B ...
From the data we have $31C=x$ and $20B=x+7$, soon $$31C=20B-7\Rightarrow20B-31C=7$$ Now just solve the Diophantine equation, am I correct?

Comment: The key sentence of the problem statement has been mangled (in translation, perhaps) and makes no sense whatsoever. That makes it rather hard to check your conversion into equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's right.

Note that this linear Diophantine equation has infinitely many solutions... I suppose the "most likely" solution is the one with positive number of horses and oxen that costs the least total.